# Any way to log off or close apps when time limits run out

Tags: macos, automation, parental-controls

My kids use Steam to play games on the Mac. Each kid gets half an hour through parental controls time limit feature.  However, it just locks their account and leaves the apps running.  Steam can only have one instance running at a time on a single computer, so the second kid can't play on Steam after the first kid has got logged out, without me giving the first kids account some extra time, and then closing steam.

Is there a smarter way to do this?  If the account was logged out at the end of the alloted time, the apps would close and no longer impact on other user accounts.

Comment: I haven't messed with parental controls in a while, but making a shell script and adding the two children accounts to the `sudoers` file for that one script would probably  let them run a clickable script to kill all Steam processes on the Mac. That way if one child forgets to quit the app, the other could "cull" it.

Comment: That's a reasonable answer - certainly smarter than what I am currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can log out an account after so many minutes via the Security and Privacy preference:

Apple Icon > System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Advanced button and then set the Log out after minutes of inactivity to a low number. This closes all the Apps on my Mac and logs me off completely for more security.

[image]

Comment: This setting affects *all* user accounts, not just the active user.